# Find empty results in jQuery filters

Tags: jquery, filter

I am facing some issue in below mention code. I just want display empty message if the search result is empty. Could you please help me to find the empty results.
I mean where should i write the code for empty result.By the way search filter is working perfectly.

```
var $rows = $('.filters > .article');

$('#search').change(function() {

    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();      
    $rows.show().filter(function() {

        var text = $(this).data('location').replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
```

Comment: Any reason why you're using a bitwise not operator `~`? You can simply check for `text.indexOf(val) < 0`.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your change event handler, you could add...

```
if($('.filters > .article:visible').length == 0) {
    // Search result is empty
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help